# Am I able to get the current value of the data grid cell during the KeyDown event

Tags: c#, wpf

I have event in data grid KeyDown. But I cant current value from updated cell. I need know value for every char changed.

```
if (DataGrid1.SelectedIndex == -1 || e.Key == Key.Enter || e.Key == Key.Tab || e.Key == Key.Escape)
    return;
var thisValueIsNull = DataGrid1.CurrentCell.Item as Person;
var thisValueIsBeforeStartUpdate = DataGrid1.SelectedItem as Person;
```

What should I do to get this value?

Code xmal:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.RowSpan="2" CanUserAddRows="False" LayoutUpdated="DataGrid1_LayoutUpdated" RowHeaderWidth="0" KeyDown="DataGrid1_KeyDown">
        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="column1" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="column2" Header="SecondName" Binding="{Binding SecondName}" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="column3" Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Age}" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="column4" Header="Country" Binding="{Binding Country}" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="column5" Header="City" Binding="{Binding City}" Width="*"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Edit:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<Person> person = new List<Person>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        person.Add(new Person() { Name = "Abb", SecondName = "AA" });
        person.Add(new Person() { Name = "Bbb", SecondName = "BB" });
        person.Add(new Person() { Name = "Ccc", SecondName = "CC" });
        DataGrid1.ItemsSource = person;
    }

    private void WordsDataGrid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

}
```

Xaml:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.RowSpan="2" CanUserAddRows="False" RowHeaderWidth="0" KeyDown="WordsDataGrid_KeyDown">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="column1" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="column2" Header="SecondName" Binding="{Binding SecondName}" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="column3" Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Age}" Width="*"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

In edit you have code this can you add to your program. It can be other event which let me take current value after every changed without click enter or changed focus.

Solution:

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" KeyUp="TextBox_KeyUp"></TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Can you add the XAML section as well as the complete event method please?

Comment: ofc I added, but it isnt nothing special.

Comment: Ok, I'm guessing the event code is in the code behind, right? The problem is probably your use of `DataGrid1.CurrentCell.Item as Person` and `DataGrid1.CurrentCell.Item` is not a instance of the `Person` class, which results in the value being null. If you debug at that line, I guess you can see the correct values in the `DataGrid1.CurrentCell.Item` variable, right?

Comment: I am looking for how to take this value. I added what I am trying and results. I wanted do it without inotifypropertychanged, but probably no.

Comment: Yes you can o it without inotifypropertychanged in the code-behind, but I guess your datagrid items contain strings. So don't use `as Person`, this tries to cast the item to a `Person` type and results `null` if it isn't possible.

Comment: This return didnt update So if name Is "Max" and I add "o" it return "Max".

Comment: Hmm...can you try to use the keyup event instead of the keydown event?

Comment: I used, but It is always "Max" does not metter how much letter you add

Comment: I check inotifypropertychanged it didnt work. Because changed in datagrid dont change list<object> and event run when you click enter.

Comment: short question: have you some `List<Person>` as itemssource of the datagrid?

Comment: Yes. DataGrid1.ItemsSource = List<Person>

Comment: I added code. If you want you can test it.

Comment: Hi, I hope it isn't too urgent, I will test around on a mockup project tomorrow as soon as I can

Comment: ok. I will try. If I could I would know.

Comment: I find solution.

Comment: Ah, cool - share it, please! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following in your KeyDown event:

```
private void Grid_KeyDown(object sender,System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    string previousValue = ((TextBox)((DataGrid)sender).CurrentCell.Column.GetCellContent(((DataGrid)sender).CurrentCell.Item)).Text;
}
```

Best wishes,
Ashkan